# Duplicate "Price as configured" block on bundle products

Tags: magento-1.7, template, bundle

I'd like to have the `price as configured` block visible both on top & on bottom (as it currently is) for the bundle product page:

[image: product-options-bottom]

Looking through `app/design/frontend/base/default/template/` I can see that this is populated by the following files:

`bundle/catalog/product/view/type/bundle.phtml` on line 45:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('bundle_prices') ?>
```

And `catalog/product/view/options/wrapper/bottom.phtml` on line 27:

```
<div class="product-options-bottom">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true);?>
</div>
```

The first one seemingly responsible for the population of the numeric pricing value based on option selection, whereas the second one is responsible for generating the block in it's entirety.

Unfortunately, the call `$this->getChildHtml('', true, true);` doesn't point me in much direction with regards to what to lookout for in the layout file.

Would really appreciate any pointer as to how I could get that block (& accompanying JS) duplicated on top (prior to the options)  instead of just below. This way the customer can see pricing without having to scroll through all the options (if there is a default configuration selected).

Like this:

[image]

Comment: Have you used template hints or Aoe Advanced template hints to find out which blocks they are?

Comment: @SanderMangel thanks, using the advanced template hints, trying to tackle it in the meantime, block in specific is `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View`

Comment: Hi, how to archive this ..?

Answer (score 1):

You can find layout definition of the block in question in `app/design/frontend/{package}/{theme}/layout/bundle.xml`.

```
<layout>
    <PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle translate="label" module="bundle">
       ...
       <reference name="product.info">
          ...
          <block type="bundle/catalog_product_price" name="bundle.prices" as="bundle_prices" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml">
               <action method="setMAPTemplate"><tmpl>catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml</tmpl></action>
          </block>
          ...
       </reference>
    </PRODUCT_TYPE_bundle>
</layout>
```

So invoking below block

```
<block type="bundle/catalog_product_price" name="bundle.prices" as="bundle_prices" template="bundle/catalog/product/view/price.phtml">
    <action method="setMAPTemplate"><tmpl>catalog/product/price_msrp_item.phtml</tmpl></action>
</block>
```

probably with some other name and alias name and call that block in appropriate template will leads to what you are trying to achieve.

---

<sup>[This answer is a part of #mageStackDay5. It is an event conducted by Magento Community members as part of increasing the question-answer ratio. For more information http://www.magestackday.com/]</sup>